# How to load test with multiple thread, single iteration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I created multiple webtests for different user performing different actions in my webapp. 
What I want to do is creating a Load Test which starts all webtests at the same time, and each runs one time only.
It seems that no Load Test Model in VS fits my case.

Does anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that. One way to do it would be to

make the number of users equal to the number of tests you have
use a constant load pattern 
in Run Settings,set "use test iterations to true" 
in Run Settings, set test iterations to the number of tests you have.

However, starting all users *exactly* at the same time usually does not make sense because it will overload the server under test. So I would say, don't use a constant load pattern, but rather use a 1 second ramp up for your users.

I believe there are other ways to do this to.